# GitHub logs truncated during Python unit tests

Tags: python, github, github-actions, python-unittest

What specific configuration or code must be changed in order to get the GitHub workflow defined below to successfully print out the complete logs of the Python 3.10 unit test that is run by the workflow?

The current failure is that:

1. The logs do not include the standard summary of tests which python unittest always prints out after unit tests. The standard test summary includes the number of tests run by unittest and the `OK` keyword to validate that all tests succeeded.
2. During forced failure like `self.assertTrue(False)`, the logs truncate at the time of failure, which is before the logs are done being printed to the GitHub web UI. This similarly leaves us with incomplete logs.

Here is the workflow code we are currently using:

```yaml
name: workflow-name
on: [push]
jobs:
  name-of-this-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: bash
        name: Run test_example.py
        run: |
          cd /home/runner/work/appName/
          python -m unittest appName.unitTests.test_controller_custom
```

But note that we are not sure if the solution might be elsewhere in the GitHub repository configuration instead of in this workflow code.